# How to stop Gmail's "Add your mobile phone to your account"?

Tags: gmail, multi-factor-auth

Gmail prompts

> Add your mobile phone to your account .Without a phone number, you could lose all access to your account if you forget your password or if your account is hijacked. Adding a phone number allows us to do things like send you SMS alerts when we detect suspicious activity" .

I press "Click here to skip adding a mobile phone to your account" but after awhile, the message appears again.

What if I do not want to add a mobile? How to get rid of this messages? What if you don't have a mobile?

Comment: Even if you add a mobile number, you're prompted to confirm it every few months. As it's an attempt to help you keep your account from being compromised I doubt that there's a way to permanently get rid of it.

Comment: And do not just add some random mobile number just to make the message go away!   Once you have entered a number, Google may choose to use it if you ever forget your password - so it's important that you do have access to any mobile-number that you give them.

Comment: You can't stop that. Google wish to collect as much data as possible (and correlate them), to serve you relevant ads.

Comment: I see this happening not only with Gmail, but also with Yahoo, Imdb, Voip

Answer (score -1):

You add alternate email ID to get rid of it.

Comment: Any source for this information?